# UIBarButtonItem with Text and Image - iOS 8

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

***SEE UPDATE BEFORE READING***

I want to put a button in a ToolBar of an iOS 8 app. That button needs to have an Image and Text.

That looks like a standard thing to do, the standard Apple apps have plenty of examples. See "Moments" with its Photos, Shared and Albums

I see plenty of questions about whether it can be done. Some saying No others saying you need a Custom View. Custom? Really? For something this normal.

It tried setting Title and Image but the caption does not display

```
var customImageBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (UIImage.FromBundle ("tools_icon"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, OnBarButtonItemClicked);
                customImageBarButtonItem.TintColor = ApplicationColors.Purple;
                customImageBarButtonItem.Title = "Caption";
                return customImageBarButtonItem;
```

I am using Xamarin.iOS

**UPDATE**

It has been pointed out to me in this [Xamarin Forums post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/111529#Comment_111529) that what I thought was a ToolBar Button in the iOS Moments app was in fact a Tab Bar and they do support Text and Image right out of the box

Answer (score 3):

When they say that you have to create a custom view, what they probably mean is that it can be as simple as just creating a UIButton with an image and text to the left of the image, and using that as your "custom view" for your UIBarButtonItem.  Technically a UIButton is a View since it inherits from UIView, so you can use that as your custom view.

```
//Create a UIButton with an image on the left, and text to the right
var buttonImage = UIImage.FromBundle("tools_icon");
var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom)
{
     Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 120, 33) //You may need to adjust as necessary
}
;
button.SetImage(buttonImage, UIControlState.Normal);
button.SetTitle("Caption", UIControlState.Normal);
button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);

//create a UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton as the custom view.
var barButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(button);
NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

Depending on the size of "tools_icon", you may need to make any necessary adjustments, but the width of the button frame must be long enough to contain both the image icon and the text.